# Magento 2 url_rewrite table contains "az-categories/" prepended to URLs for all of our stores

Tags: magento2, category, multistore, url-rewrite, magento-2.1.4

We have a multi-store Magento 2.1.4 installation, with 3 stores, and in recent weeks we've noticed that our category URLs will some times include one of our store code's prepended with "-categories/" to all of our URLs.

Eg. **az-categories/wheel-brake-tire/brake.html** when it should be **wheel-brake-tire/brake.html** where **az** is the store code.

After investigating this further we discovered that any time we save a category the system generates more URLs like this.

It creates these URLs for each Store ID but only adds one Store Code to the URL. All stores will have a URL of **az-categories/wheel-brake-tire/brake.html** One row where `store_id = 1`, another where `store_id = 2` and a third where `store_id = 3`.

We don't want this occurring on any of our sites.

We've disabled our custom extensions in our local environment and it still occurs. We also tried to prevent this by commenting out the Magento code in `vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/CataegoryUrlRewriteGenerator.php` as a test but it still occurred.

Does anyone know how to resolve this so that the system no longer generates these extra URLS and returns our categories are back to normal?

Thanks.

Comment: Try Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> General -> "Enable Single-Store Mode" set to Yes & Check Go to Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Url Options -> Add Store Code to Urls should be No

Comment: Why would we enable single store mode if we're using multiple stores?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable `Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Url Options -> Add Store Code to Urls` option and clean the cache